Audio and Video out of Sync with WebRTC Rust Server and Browser Client
When building a WebRTC backend using WebRTC-rs, i have the issue, that audio and video are not in sync.
The audio is encoded as Opus and the Video as H264. If i understood the library/webrtc correctly, video and audio are synced automatically, if timestamps are close enough. So i tried the following:
This is running in a tokio task:
let mut h264 = H264Reader::<&[u8]>::new(video_buffer.as_ref(), 1_048_576);
let mut ticker = tokio::time::interval(Duration::from_millis(20));

loop {
    let nal = match h264.next_nal() {
        Ok(nal) => nal,
        Err(webrtc::media::Error::ErrIoEOF) => break,
        Err(err) => {
            return Err(err.into());
        }
    };

    video_track
        .write_sample(&Sample {
            data: nal.data.freeze(),
            duration: Duration::from_millis(40),
            ..Default::default()
        })
        .await?;
    let _ = ticker.tick().await;

and this in another tokio task:
let mut ticker = tokio::time::interval(Duration::from_millis(10));
for chunk in framed_pcm {
    let encoded = opus_encoder
        .encode_vec(&chunk, 20000)
        .map_err(anyhow::Error::from)?;
    audio_output_track
        .write_sample(&Sample {
            data: Bytes::copy_from_slice(&encoded),
            duration: Duration::from_millis(10),
            ..Default::default()
        })
        .await?;
    let _ = ticker.tick().await;
}

This is based on the example: https://github.com/webrtc-rs/webrtc/blob/master/examples/examples/play-from-disk-h264/play-from-disk-h264.rs
Both tasks are started directly after each other, but are not in sync. If i save both streams to a file and mux them together using ffmpeg, everything is in sync.
Playback is done with the following frontend code:
rtcPeerConnection.addEventListener("track", (event) => {
  if (event.track.kind === "audio") {
    if (this.audioRef.current) {
      this.audioRef.current.srcObject = event.streams[0];
    }
  } else if (event.track.kind === "video") {
    if (this.videoRef.current) {
      this.videoRef.current.srcObject = event.streams[0];
    }
  }
});

Playback is working fine, except the synchronization problem.

Is it possible to have audio and video synced to the same  element?
